# nginx+fastcgi+php-fpm step from standard config = 404

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm, fastcgi

I want to work simple url like `http://host/test.php`, note there are no
trailing `/` at the end.

I start from standard config from nginx site + serverfault:

```
 location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.php)(.*)$;
                if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
                        return 404;
                }
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
                fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $fastcgi_path_info;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
        }
```

end `http://host/test.php/` works, but `http://host/test.php` without trailing `/` do not work.

I try to change to such config:

```
   location ~ \.php$ {
           fastcgi_split_path_info ^/(.+\.php)(.*)$;
           if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
                   return 404;
           }
           include fastcgi_params;
           fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
           fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $fastcgi_path_info;
           fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $fastcgi_script_name;
           fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
           fastcgi_index index.php;
   }
```

and I got 404, and get from php-fpm

> Primary script unknown

So have you idea how to make `http://host/test.php` works without trailing `/`?
I tried many variants, but failed to understand what is wrong. I used nginx 1.8.1

**Update**

**1)** This problem only appears if I set `chroot` in `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`

**2)** I find out using `strace` that for url with `test.php/` php-fpm got 
`SCRIPT_NAME/test.php\v\n` and with url `test.php` I got `SCRIPT_NAME/test.php\v\t`. So first one end with '\n' and second one end with '\t' can not get why.

**Update 2**
Looks like a bug, I try 1.9.13 and the same config,
not working with 1.8.1, works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The first block works for me (with or without trailing slash), so there may be another conflicting location in your configuration which prevents one variant from working.

The second block is not capturing the leading '/' of the URI so the test `if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name)` always fails.

I presume that your `php-fpm` configuration must already know your document root, because it is usual to define `SCRIPT_FILENAME` as the full path:

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

Comment: yes, php-fpm do chroot to value of `$document_root`. What version of nginx do you have?

Comment: @user1034749 I am testing on 1.8.0

Comment: Looks like problem in php-frm, if remove chroot directive and add $document_root `test.php` works, if I enable chroot in php-fpm works only `test.php/`

Comment: I update my question, if you can please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

When using chroot for PHP-FPM, you have to define `SCRIPT_FILENAME` relative to the chroot environment. `SCRIPT_FILENAME` tells PHP-FPM where to find your script.

For example, if your web site index page is in `/var/www/index.php`, and your chroot is set to `/var/www`, the `SCRIPT_FILENAME` has to be `/index.php` instead of `/var/www/index.php`, which is the default nginx sets.

So, you have to insert the directory inside the chroot before `$fastcgi_script_name` in your configuration, so that PHP-FPM will find your script.

Comment: As you see I already done this, see line `SCRIPT_FILENAME $fastcgi_script_name` in my config, my `chroot == $document_root`, and php-fpm find file if I add `/` at the end, see again my question, so I configure in almost right way, the problem in `\n` vs `\t`, but I doubt that this is related to prefix of filename